# what to use instead of glGetAttribLocation for gl versions < 2.0

Tags: opengl, glsl

is there a way to get the id of a variable if the opengl version is smaller than 2.0?

glGetAttribLocation is only available since 2.0

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using GLSL via the ARB extensions (GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_vertex_shader and GL_ARB_fragment_shader), you need to use glGetAttribLocationARB, from the [GL_ARB_vertex_shader extension](http://code.google.com/p/glextensions/wiki/GL_ARB_vertex_shader).

If you are not using those extensions and not using OpenGL >= 2.0, then you don't need to use glGetAttribLocation since it requires a vertex shader to be present.

Answer (score 0):

`GLSL` is only available since GL 2.0. That's when `glGetAttribLocation` was added.

If you can get to the entrypoints to create a GLSL vertex shader, then you can, in the same way, get access to the `glGetAttribLocation` entrypoint.